# WPF ComboBox not firing SelectionChanged event if placed at the bottom of Word AddIn

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, vsto

I'm developing Office Word AddIn and using WPF controls for user interface inside WinForms UserControl as a container (inside ElementHost control).

The problem I noticed with ComboBox is that it doesn't fire SelectionChanged event if placed at the bottom of AddIn for items near to the bottom of Word application. For instance, I can click and choose first listed item (if lucky), otherwise ComboBox dropdown (popup) will be closed and SelectionChanged event will not be fired. Instead, Word performs some actions like zooming or changing page layout - actions that are located at the right bottom of Word application, if Addin is located at the right side.

The only workaround I found is that I use ComboBox popup 'upsided'. In that case, events are firing well. As I said, this is a workaround, and I would like to see some smarter solution.

P.S.:If I'm using WinForms ComboBox control, placing it to the bottom doesn't cause this issues - SelectedIndexChanged event works as expected.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I added some very basic sample code.

Sample code: WpfControl.xaml - UI

```
<UserControl x:Class="WordAddIn.WpfControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox x:Name="cboItems" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                  DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
                  SelectionChanged="cboItems_SelectionChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Sample code: WpfControl.xaml.cs - Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WordAddIn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WpfControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WpfControl : UserControl
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string NAME { get; set; }
        }

        public WpfControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                itemList.Add(new Item { ID = i, NAME = "Item " + i });
            }

            cboItems.ItemsSource = itemList;
        }

        private void cboItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = ((object[])(e.AddedItems)).ToList().FirstOrDefault() as Item;

                MessageBox.Show("Item: " + item.NAME + " clicked");

                e.Handled = true;
            }

            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

WpfContrainer that contains element host and WpfControl as a element host child is added as a Addin on button click on the Word Ribbon.

Sample code:  RibbonWord.cs

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    WpfContainer wpfContainer = new WpfContainer();

    var wpfContainerPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(wpfContainer, "AddIn");

    wpfContainerPane.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: I updated question with sample code (not the possible solution with upsided style for ComboBox).. Not quite sure how will it help, bacause it is very, very basic stuff, but here it is. In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. SelectionChanged does not work when dropdown located outside of wpf. Try change your code in this way

Xaml:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="cboItems" 
             Grid.Row="1" 
             Margin="10,10,10,10"
             DisplayMemberPath="NAME"
             SelectionChanged="cboItems_SelectionChanged"
             DropDownOpened="ComboBox_OnDropDownOpened"
             DropDownClosed="ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed" />
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WordAddIn
{        
    public partial class WpfControl : UserControl
    {
        // your code

        private DispatcherFrame dispatcherFrame;           

        private object DispatcherOperationBegin(object arg)
        {
            dispatcherFrame = new DispatcherFrame();
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(dispatcherFrame);
            return null;
        }

        private void ComboBox_OnDropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatcherOperationCallback(DispatcherOperationBegin), null);
        }

        private void ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherFrame.Continue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

More information about *DispatcherFrame* you can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152137/DispatcherFrame-Look-in-Depth).